# Is Goddess Kali mentioned in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, kali

I know Goddess Kali mentioned in Puranas and Tantras too. But, Is any mention of  Goddess Kali in Mahabharata?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, There is.**

> Mahabharata, Sauptika Parva, Chapter 8, Verse 69-70

[image]

> Arjuna too uses the epithets of "Kali" , "Mahakali" and "Bhadrakali" while singing
> his hymn to Durga in the Bhisma Parva.

[image]

> Also, Shanti Parva mentions, Bhadrakali, the form of Kali appeared with Veerabhadra to destroy Daksha's yajna.